# Login Page with ASP.NET Core (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to learn asp.net core (MVC) , and I am posting this question after trying to implement everything that I could understand from Google.

I want to create a simple login Page. I have earlier worked on asp.net framework with ado.net and webforms using edmx, but I learned that edmx and webforms are now outdated. So, I wanted to learn the new method.

These are the tables and stored procedure I created

```
create table users(userId int identity(1,1) primary key, username varchar(20), password varchar(20))

create proc login(
@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(20)
)
as
begin
if exists(select * from users where username = @username and password=@password)
select 'Success' as UserExists
else
select 'Failed' as UserExists
end
```

Then I created the Model Class -

```
 public class Login
    {   
        [Key]
        public int userId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is requried!")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is requried!")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I added model in my project. I referred this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Then referencing the following link, I added my connection string details in appstring.json file -

link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-asp-net-core-mvc-net-5-0/

```
 "WebsiteContext": "Server=DELL\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=website;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

This is startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<WebsiteContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebsiteContext")));

            
        }
```

I created the login.cshtml with basic asp.net.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h1>Login</h1>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="username"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="password"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="submit"></asp:Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now, I am confused as how should I proceed next. Here is my LoginController class. This was generated automatically after scaffolding.

```
 public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebsiteContext _context;

        public LoginController(WebsiteContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Login
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Login.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Login/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var login = await _context.Login
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.userId == id);
            if (login == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(login);
        }

        // GET: Login/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Login/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("userId,username,password")] Login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(login);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(login);
        }
    }
```

I know the process of ado.net but now I am confused how should I proceed with mvc.

Please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: While you can do that, I would instead suggest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio. As this will give you email verification, password hashing, login cookies, etc, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just do a simple login test, you need to add the verification that the username and password are consistent with the database in the controller. You can refer to the following code：

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         var User = from m in _context.Login select m;
         User = User.Where(s => s.username.Contains(model.username));
         if (User.Count() != 0)
         {
             if (User.First().password == model.password)
             {
                  return RedirectToAction("Success");
             }
         }
    }
      return RedirectToAction("Fail");
}

public IActionResult Success()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Fail()
{
   return View();
}
```

login.cshtml:

```
@model _2022070401.Models.Login
<h1>Login</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                <span asp-validation-for="username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Success:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Fail:

[image]
[image]

If you have a business need for this, I recommend using Identity. You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [this one](https://www.findandsolve.com/articles/login-and-registration-using-identity-in-asp-dot-net-core-dot-net-5#:%7E:text=NET%20Core%20Identity%20is%20an%20API%20that%20supports,details%20such%20as%20email%20id%2C%20username%2C%20and%20password.).